# Map an xyz coordinate inside a hexahedron to normalized 0-1 space

Tags: matrices, change-of-basis

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:

- I have 8 coordinates in a 3D space that define a hexahedron (a distorted cube).
- Next, I have a new arbitrary 3D coordinate in that space.
- How do I map this new coordinate into the hexahedron's space where 0-1 defines the space inside the hexahedron in each axis?

Research I have done leads me to think the answer lies in matrix math "change of basis" operations. However, since it appears that the solution would need to account for a non-linear transformation (the coordinates of any face of the hexahedron could form a trapezoid, for example) I am not sure where to look next. It seems the solution should be a fairly straightforward matrix math... but what? I am not sure where to even look next.

If you can please reply carefully, as I am from a non-math background.

Comment: How irregular or distorted the hexahedron is? This sounds like perspective projection matrix operation which maps a frustum into a cube.

Comment: The hexahedron is specified via 8 vertices. Does this mean that it might not be a parallelepiped? That’s not completely clear from your question.

Comment: The positions of the 8 verts are not guaranteed to be parallelpiped.

Comment: @peterwhy The hexahedron will most likely be quite regular and cube-like.  However, within a certain range of those verts, there is no guarantee where they will lay and the translation should be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tri-linear parametrisation that I recommend is

$$
{\vec x} = {\vec A}  +{\vec B}\xi  +{\vec C}\eta  +{\vec D}\omega+   {\vec E}\xi\eta+ {\vec F}\eta\omega+  {\vec G}\xi\omega+  {\vec H} \xi\eta\omega
$$

Where $\xi, \eta, \omega \in [0,1]$ and the vectors ${\vec A \cdots \vec H}$ can be calculated in succession from the 8 vertices characterising the hexahedron.

Note that this parametrisation also applies to a distorted hexahedron where the faces are non-planar but are governed by a bi-linear map. The edges are of course, straight.

With respect to the figure below, I've deliberately not labeled the axes as $x$, $y$ or $z$. All that's needed is a Right-Handed Coordinate system and the vertex coordinates of any two opposite faces of the hexahedron such that the opposite pairs $\{\vec{x_0}, \vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2}, \vec{x_3} \}$ and $\{{\vec x_4}, {\vec x_5}, {\vec x_6}, {\vec x_7}\}$ are both ordered clockwise looking in from the respective outward normals to the faces. There is also absolutely no requirement that ${\vec x_7}$ lie "above" or alongside ${\vec x_0}$ which is just illustrated thusly for convenience of rendering the hexahedron (I also didn't want to push the limits of my very meager artistic talent!)

With this ordering, the vectors ${\vec A \cdots \vec H}$ of the parametrisation are

$$
{\vec A} = {\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec B} = {\vec x_1}-{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec C} = {\vec x_3}-{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec D} = {\vec x_7}-{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec E} = {\vec x_2}-{\vec x_1}-{\vec x_3}+{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec F} = {\vec x_4}-{\vec x_3}-{\vec x_7}+{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec G} = {\vec x_6}-{\vec x_1}-{\vec x_7}+{\vec x_0}
\\
{\vec H} = {\vec x_5}+{\vec x_1}+{\vec x_3}+{\vec x_7}-{\vec x_6}-{\vec x_4}-{\vec x_2}-{\vec x_0}
$$

Note the following:

1) **The qualifier "Distorted" is necessary because the classical definition of polyhedra requires planar faces.** The faces with the current parametrisation can of course be planar, but is is the user's responsibility to ensure that such is the case.

2) the polyhedron can be distorted and twisted as long as

(a) The tri-linear parametrisation still holds

(b) No two faces of the hexahedron intersect

(c) The 8 vertices are ordered as described above with two pairs of 4 vertices each corresponding to opposite faces.

[image]

The way to calculate ${\vec A \cdots \vec H}$ is as follows:

Each vertex has a specific and distinct set of $\xi$, $\eta$ and $\omega$ coordinates in parametric space.

First set $\xi=\eta=\omega=0$ in the parametrisation. This corresponds to the vertex ${\vec x}_0$ giving you at once

$${\vec A}={\vec x_0}$$

Now set $\xi=1; \eta=\omega=0$ corresponding to vertex ${\vec x}_1$ which then gives you

$${\vec B}={\vec x_1}-{\vec x_0}$$

and likewise for ${\vec C}$ (with $\eta=1; \xi=\omega=0$ at vertex $\vec x_3$ ) and ${\vec D}$ (with $\omega=1; \xi=\eta=0$ at vertex $\vec x_7$ )

Now corresponding to vertex ${\vec x_2}$, we have $\xi=\eta=1;\omega=0$ which gives you

$${\vec x}_2= = {\vec A}  +{\vec B}  +{\vec C} +   {\vec E}$$

which substituting the known values of ${\vec A}$, ${\vec B}$ and ${\vec C}$

is

$${\vec E} = {\vec x_2}-{\vec x_1}-{\vec x_3}+{\vec x_0}$$

and likewise for ${\vec F}$ (with $\eta=\omega=1;\xi=0$ at vertex $\vec x_4$ ) and ${\vec G}$ (with $\xi=\omega=1;\eta=0$ at vertex $\vec x_6$ ).

Finally, substituting $\xi=\eta=\omega=1$ (vertex ${\vec x_5}$)gives you

$$
{\vec x_5} = {\vec A}  +{\vec B} +{\vec C}  +{\vec D}+   {\vec E}+ {\vec F}+  {\vec G}+  {\vec H} 
$$

and substituting in the know values of ${\vec A \cdots \vec G}$ results in

$$
{\vec H} = {\vec x_5}+{\vec x_1}+{\vec x_3}+{\vec x_7}-{\vec x_6}-{\vec x_4}-{\vec x_2}-{\vec x_0}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply!  If you could break it down a  bit that would be great!  I am definitely a layman in terms of math.
I can understand pseudo-code, if that helps.
Solving for a distorted hexahedron is exactly the problem  I need to solve for!

Comment: As promised, I've augmented my answer with a sketch and more details of the parametrisation. Please note the distinction that I'm making between a "Distorted" and an "Irregular" hexahedron - the latter merely deviates from established shapes like a cube, cuboid or parallepiped while retaining planar faces while the former has faces that are non-planar.

Comment: So just to  be clear, if I wanted to solve for an arbitrary point ξ,η,ω would be the the normalized hexahedron relative coordinate?
And in the first formula, x is the original non-normalized coordinate?

Also, I am assuming that the little arrows above the variables means to apply it to x/y/z respectively?

It feels like something is missing, because the formula needs to take in all xyz of the input coordinate in order to be able to solve properly.  (Probably I am missing something, though?!)

Sorry if I am being daft!  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The answers to your first two questions are "Yes"  and "Yes". The answer to the third is that the arrows refer to the $\bf vectors$ $ {\vec x_k},  k=0\cdots 7$ each of which has three components $x,y,z$, in essence ${\vec x}=\{x,y,z\}$.. So when you calculate the vectors ${\vec A}\cdots{\vec H}$, you are really calculating all three components of each of them, ($A_x,A_y,A_z$) and so on. Hope this helps. If not, let me know.

Comment: It seems wrong to me though,  because let's say the part where I am solving for ξ.   In that calculation it must take into account all 3 axis of the arbitrary point to get the correct result (each axis solution is based on some kind of lerp based on the other 2 axis of the arbitrary point). In this formula it only uses x to solve for ξ, so it must be incorrect. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, we do not using $x,y,z$ to calculate $\xi$ at all. In fact, it's the other way around. Anyway, since the site seems to discourage extended comments, see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Also, my sincere apologies for forgetting to complete the expressions for the vectors ${\vec A}$ ... ${\vec H}$. I started it on my iPhone and forgot to fix them when I made it to my computer.

Comment: Hi Sharat,  I believe I understand now what you mean, but I still do not understand how to use these formulas to convert the arbitrary coordinate into the hexahedron's normalized coordinate.   Sorry if I am being daft.

Comment: Aaah! You want the inverse transformation!! OK. Stand by.

Comment: [+1] @Sharat V Chandrasekhar for this very good answer, that takes into account the more general case of non planar surfaces (replaced by pieces of hyperbolic paraboloids) and your dedication  for answering the numerous questions !

Comment: I wanted to just follow up here that I did implement this solution and it worked.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Super! Glad it worked out correctly. I wonder if this approach could be modified to account for an octohedron!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the inverse transformation, then I personally cannot think of a way around solving a non-linear set of equations in $\xi$, $\eta$ and $\omega$. However this task can be simplified somewhat by constructing 3 vectors that are orthogonal to the 3 pairs $\vec E$ and $\vec H$, $\vec F$ and $\vec H$, and $\vec G$ and $\vec H$ as

$$
\vec J=\vec E\times \vec H
\\
\vec K=\vec F\times \vec H
\\
\vec L=\vec G\times \vec H
$$

Now, if you dot the given vector $\vec x$ with each of them, you have a set of equations that is at most bi-linear according to:

$$
f(\xi, \eta,\omega)=
 ({\vec B\cdot\vec J})\xi
+({\vec C\cdot\vec J})\eta
+({\vec D\cdot\vec J})\omega
+({\vec F\cdot\vec J})\eta\omega
+({\vec G\cdot\vec J})\xi\omega
+({\vec A-\vec x})\cdot\vec J=0
$$

$$
g(\xi, \eta,\omega)=({\vec B\cdot\vec K})\xi
+({\vec C\cdot\vec K})\eta
+({\vec D\cdot\vec K})\omega
+({\vec E\cdot\vec K})\xi\eta
+({\vec G\cdot\vec K})\xi\omega
+({\vec A-\vec x})\cdot\vec K=0
$$

and

$$
h(\xi, \eta,\omega)=
 ({\vec B\cdot\vec L})\xi
+({\vec C\cdot\vec L})\eta
+({\vec D\cdot\vec L})\omega
+({\vec E\cdot\vec L})\xi\eta
+({\vec F\cdot\vec L})\eta\omega
+({\vec A-\vec x})\cdot\vec L=0
$$

which can be solved by a 3-dimensional version of the Newton-Raphson iteration. Convergence should not take more than a handful of iterations.

In fact if the initial guess is good enough, you might even be able to get by with linearising the set of equations (i.e., freezing the non-linear terms at the current estimates of  $\xi$, $\eta$ and $\omega$, solving the linear system and updating the non-linear terms during each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your replies and patience Sharat!
I had thought of a few ways of approximating the answer.
The solution is much more involved than I imagined!

Answer (score 0):

In the very special case of a regular hexahedron to be placed in correspondence with a cube, here is how one can proceed.

It suffices to take the matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
    1/2  &  -1/4 &   -1/4\\
    0  &  \sqrt{3}/4 &   -\sqrt{3}/4\\
       \sqrt{3}/2   &   \sqrt{3}/2  &   \sqrt{3}/2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
       0.5000  & -0.2500  & -0.2500\\
         0  &  0.4330  & -0.4330\\
    0.8660 &   0.8660  &  0.8660
\end{pmatrix},$$

where the columns of $M$ are the images of vectors of canonical basis $\begin{pmatrix}
   1\\
   0\\
   0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
   1\\
   0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
   0\\
   0\\
   1
\end{pmatrix}$ resp.

giving the transformation formulas:

$$\begin{cases}
    x' &=&   0.5000 x &  - & 0.2500y  & - & 0.2500z\\
    y' &=&   & & 0.4330 y &  -& 0.4330z\\
    z' &=&   0.8660x  & + & 0.8660y & +&  0.8660z
\end{cases}$$

($(x,y,z)$,  coordinates attached to the cube, $(x',y',z')$ attached to the hexahedron).

**Remark 1 :** the mutual dot products of the colomns of $M$ are obtained as the coefficients of the matrix:

$$M^TM=\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &  5/8 &  5/8\\
    5/8  &  1 &   5/8\\
    5/8   & 5/8 &  1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

One can see thus

- they are all with norm 1,
- all dot-products are the same, giving rhombi (the faces of the hexahedron) acute angles acos$(5/8) \approx 51.3^{\circ}.$

**Remark 2 :**

If you want to do the reverse (passing from coordinates in the hexahedron to coordinates in the cube), take the coefficients of the inverse of matrix $M$,

$$ M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}   1.3333 &  -0.0000  &  0.3849\\
   -0.6667  &  1.1547  &  0.3849\\
   -0.6667  & -1.1547  &  0.3849\end{pmatrix}.$$

[image]

Comment: From the OP’s description of the hexahedron being defined by 8 points, I don’t think that a parallelepiped was meant. The problem is certainly *much* simpler for a parallelepiped. I’ve asked for clarification.

Comment: I haven't read with sufficient attention the test of the OP. I keep my text in order to show how one proceed in the regular case.

Comment: Certainly. The irregular case would use an extension of this solution, so it’s a good starting point, anyway.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replies!  The positions of the verts are not parallelpiped.  They are only guaranteed to make a convex hexahedron.